# My 12yo. daughter told me she's gay, but not my wife. What should I do?

Tags: parents, communication, lgbtq

Ok backdrop..My wife and daughter kinda have that butting heads type relationship which has made it always easier for me to be close to my daughter.

Just a few days ago my  daughter and I talked about a pic she drew a few months ago. My wife has known about this pic and she felt we shouldn't talk about it anymore until she confided in us.  Well i know for a fact she will not confide in my wife when it comes to a lot of things especially her sexuality.

So with that being said it referenced her being gay.  This was surprising for both of us but yet for me This actually makes complete sense. So fast forward 2 months later my daughter said a few nights ago that she thinks we have a really close and gave me the biggest hug.  She knows I have her back and I will protect her.

So I went against my wife's wishes to not bring it up to her. It was the most amazing talk I have ever had with her and our bond is even stronger! She came out to me,  I asked her if I should tell mom and she was adamant about not telling her.

What should I do? I don't want to make my daughter she can't confide in both parents but yet I would like to discuss this with my wife. Oh and my wife is very jealous of our relationship which is so ridiculous.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because opinion-based, open ended questions (e.g. "What should I do?") are off topic for this site. If you want to know how to help your daughter to communicate with her mother, that's a specific question that we can answer. If you want to change the question, please edit it and flag for reopening. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not your secret, it is hers.

If she wants to inform her mother she should do so herself, it's not your palce to do it.

I've always been closer with my father than my mother, and he never betrayed my trust and if he did i doubt our relationship would have been as good as it is now.

Also ask your daughter WHY she doesn't want her mom to know it, perhaps it's a silly reason (like she believes her mom is anti lesbian while she isn't) and then you might be able to support her relationship with her mother.

If it's a serious issue like she is afraid her mother would out her and she is actually the kind of type that would...then it's better to play innocent and act like you didn't know about it when it eventually comes out... Because if her mother finds out you already knew it might straight their relation even further and your relationship with your wife.

But on a side note, your daughter is 12... I know at least 20 girls who went through a lesbian/bi phase in their teenage years and are now straight again... this might blow over so don't try to make it a bigger deal than it possibly is.